# Php $num_rows not working after installing Mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows, mysqlnd

I'm trying to get my `$num_rows` working. It had been working, and now it's not. Reading this site it was suggested I install `MySqlnd` on my server because some things like `fetch_array` and `get_result` were not working and now it's like I wish I'd never installed it. (Should I uninstall it?)

I've been trying so many variations of things to try get `$num_rows` working - and other functions - I don't know what is right or wrong anymore. Can you help ? The error I am getting is :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::stmt() in /var/www/html/checkcontact.php on line 34
```

Line 34 is : `$result = $con->stmt($query);`

Here's my code :

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');

//post all contacts in my phone as a JSON array
$json = $_POST['phonenumber'];
//decode the JSON
$array = json_decode($json);
//bind 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
 $stmt = $con->prepare($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $phonenumber);

 //for each value of phone_number in the array, call it $phonenumber
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        $phonenumber = $value->phone_number;

$stmt->execute();
$result = $con->stmt($query);
//$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
//$stmt->store_result();
//$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows();
 //$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

 if ($result->$num_rows > 0) {
    //  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

    // $contact_id = $row['user_id'];
    // echo $contact_id;

    echo "number of phone numbers in the user table is " . $num_rows  . "<br>"; 
     }
 }
 ?>
```

EDIT : 
Here is my dbConnect.php file, as requested :

```
<?php

define ('HOST', 'localhost');
define ('USER', 'bob');
define ('PASS', 'password');
define ('DB', 'mydb');

$con = NEW MySQLi("localhost", "bob", "password", "mydb");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

Comment: It seems the fault is not in your `$num_rows` method. Can you post the dbConnect.php file? This is where your `$con` variable  comes from right? (Dont forget to remove passwords!)

Comment: @Clemenz Thanks, edited post to include my dbConnect.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is this line

```
$result = $con->stmt($query);
```

You probably want to `get_result()` instead.

There is no `mysqli::stmt()` method. Then, there's no `$result->$num_rows`, but it's a property of the result, which means it should be `$result->num_rows` (loose the `$`).

Revised with those changes, this is most likely how your code should look like.

```
//post all contacts in my phone as a JSON array
$json = $_POST['phonenumber'];
//decode the JSON
$array = json_decode($json);
//bind 
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query) or die($con->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $phonenumber) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt->error);

//for each value of phone_number in the array, call it $phonenumber
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $phonenumber = $value->phone_number;
    $stmt->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt->error);

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { // Check if there are any rows matching this value
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); // Convert from MySQLi_stmt to MySQLi_result (to use fetch_assoc())
        echo "Number of rows matching username '".$value->phone_number."' from user-table is " . $result->num_rows  . " rows.<br>"; 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['user_id']."<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No rows matching username ".$value->phone_number.".<br />";
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Note that the `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` method requires the mysqlnd driver. If you don't have that driver, you will have to fetch the results differently, using `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` and `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` (aside from that, installing that driver - if installed correctly - won't affect your code).

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: +1. No errors now but it goes to the else statement - No rows matching, even though there are clearly phone numbers in my JSON array that are in my user table. Any ideas ?

Comment: That shouldn't matter from the MySQL point of view, I'd start by checking that the values of `$value->phone_number` are *exactly* what you expect them to be.

Comment: Yes, your code just takes some tinkering, I'll figure it out. When I change it to `if ($stmt->num_rows == 0)` it echoes correctly, weird. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That means that there weren't any rows returned for that username, though. Weird, indeed. Hopefully it helped you on your way at least ;-) *Cheers*